# Is it possible to deploy JSF application on Bluemix?

Tags: jsf, ibm-cloud

I have installed IBM Bluemix tools on Eclipse and created a 'Hello World' JSF and EAR project. While creating I have chosen a Bluemix runtime environment. Now I try to deploy EAR from Eclipse, it successfully deployed and started but when I try to open it I get the following error:

```
Not Found The application or context root for this request has not been found: [Ljava.lang.Object;@bdb04149
```

What have I missed? Is there comprehensive tutorial to deploy Java EE web applications on Bluemix available anywhere?

Comment: Were you able to run the EAR file locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deployed an EAR (containing your JSF app) you need to add the web module name to the URL, for example, if your project is called `testJSF`, your URL will look like this:

```
http://testApp.mybluemix.net/testJSF/
```

And of course, if your web page is not called `index.xxx` you need to add the web page name as well, for example:

```
http://testApp.mybluemix.net/testJSF/textPage.xhtml
```

or

```
http://testApp.mybluemix.net/testJSF/textPage.faces
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy complete EAR files on Bluemix yes. Using the eclipse tools also makes it much easier. This link has steps on how you can do this https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#manageapps/eclipsetools.html

Further down the page (you can use the menu on the left too) there are steps on how to push an EAR. It might be with pushing a complete Liberty profile to get finer control on the application behavior. This link has further details on pushing Liberty apps and the profile itself https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty